# How to fix Emacs client *ERROR*: Arithmetic error

Tags: linux, emacs, ubuntu-10.04

GNU Emacs 23.1.1

I've noticed that if I run Emacs and `M-x server-start`, I can use the `emacsclient` program as usual, but if if I start Emacs using `emacs --daemon` and then try to use `emacsclient` the new frame locks up and the shell outputs `*ERROR*: Arithmetic error`.

This issue doesn't happen if I use the `-t` flag to force terminal mode when running `emacsclient`.

Has anyone run into this before? Anyone know what's going on and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Try to run `emacs --deamon -q` to skip your .emacs, or `emacs --deamon -Q` to skip site file. If it work with the first one, then the problem is in the .emacs, if only the second one work, then the problem is with one of the package installed on your distribution, if both failed, the problem is with your version of .emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is (or, at least, seems to be) a variation of an issue I've had previously. For some reason the line

`'(default ((t (:background "black" :foreground "white"))))`

in my custom faces settings causes a lot of problems. Before it would just throw an error and complain about a color not existing whenever I ran `emacsclient -c`, but now it was completely freezing the frame.

I wasn't using any custom color theme when I originally added those settings, but now that I am it looks like I can remove it without any side-effects.

Comment: Strangely, I was getting `Arithmetic error` in GNU Emacs for Mac OS X 24.3 (9.0) when editing python code.  When I removed the custom-faces section from my .emacs it solved the problem.  I also had `:background "Black" :foreground "White"` in there along with other things.  I replaced them with a `-rv` command-line option.

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, this exact custom option was the cause of the pb for me too, even though I use a lot of other faces customization, this is the only one to remove in order to run `emacsclient -c`